# convert properties to javascript object ( bad character result)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some problems with characters (ä, å, ö) usually I convert them to

```
å=\u00e5
ä=\u00e4
ö=\u00f6
```

I cannot get rid of these right now because I am using an old technology Apache Wicket.
my Language.proprites file looks like this

```
calendar-event-group-configuration=Konfigurationsgrupp f\u00f6r 
evenemang
```

When I am reading .properties files I get in the console ( using a npm package called ('properties-reader')) :

```
Konfigurationsgrupp f\\u00f6r evenemang
```

I expect getting:

```
Konfigurationsgrupp för evenemang
```

or

```
   Konfigurationsgrupp f\u00f6r evenemang
```

**but this does happen because my code adds one more** backslash **to the value because of using the npm package 'properties-reader'**

here is my code :

```
const fs = require("fs");
const PropertiesReader = require("properties-reader");
const properties = PropertiesReader("./Language_sv.properties").getAllProperties();
console.log(properties);
```

anyone has a better idea to get all properties in on object

Language_sv.properties   is the file has :

```
 calendar-event-group-configuration=Konfigurationsgrupp f\u00f6r 
 evenemang
```

**I found another package called ('properties') does not have the issue with the one above but I do not know **how i can get the object (obj) out side of the function****

```
const fs = require("fs");
var prop = require ("properties");

prop.parse ("./Language_sv.properties", { path: true }, function (error, obj){
  if (error) return console.error (error);
  
  console.log (obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape?retiredLocale=it)

```js
const property = "calendar-event-group-configuration=Konfigurationsgrupp f\u00f6r evenemang"

console.log(unescape(property));
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like to have a solution after using the npm package since I need the data as an object

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that properties-reader does not understand unicode characters. One way to go around it is to postprocess the property values after it was read.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const PropertiesReader = require("properties-reader");
const properties = PropertiesReader("./Language_sv.properties", 'utf-8').getAllProperties();
console.log(properties);
for(let i in properties){
    properties[i] = properties[i].split('"').join('\\"')
    properties[i] = decodeURIComponent(
        JSON.parse('"' +properties[i] + '"')
    )
}
console.log(properties);
```

Here I covert property value into a string enclosed within quotes, and then parse it with JSON.parse. It parses the escaped backslash properly. And decodeURIComponent coverts unicode escape sequence to the character.

Comment: I do not think this is a practical solution because I have Quotation mark  in the .properties files , do you have an idea how we can avoid this conflict @Vladimir M

Comment: this is a practical solution to the original question.

there are ways to handle quotes as well. I would replace those with escaped sequences (updated  the answer code with the modification)